# What transistor to use?

Tags: transistors, npn, tesla-coil

I found a schematic, but it requires 2N2222A transistor, is there any alternative? I have only KC637, can I use it? I'm new to electronics, and I'm not from US/UK, so sorry my English.

Comment: Do you understand what specifications of the transistor are important?

Comment: No, I'm only 12 years old, and I can't find any web, book... about electrical engineering, plus I'm not from English speaking country

Comment: Hi Kraftinger, if you post your schematic we can help you to find out a compatible part. And don't worry, your English is fine.

Comment: Maybe video would be better: [How to make mini tesla coil at home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SF4KPqNK4c)

Comment: Better is a schematic drawing, with parts list and a written description of the circuit, how to build it, and how it works, together with a description of what to do when things don't work.  It is hard to put much information into a video, so nobody really tries.

Comment: [Here is a link to a good article on building a Tesla coil.](http://www.teslauniverse.com/resources/builders/plans/build-solid-state-tesla-coil). Down load the PDF at the end.  It is a well written magazine article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will probably work although the KC637 is lower frequency than the 2N2222. This circuit probably operates at ~1MHz which is well below the 50MHz ft. The other parameters look better or okay enough.

The pins are in a different order compared to the 2N2222 so you will have to account for that. The 2N2222 is E-B-C and the KC637 is C-B-E. So, just flip the transistor over. Also both are different from the BC637.

Pay attention to the direction of winding on the coils.

Answer (score 2):

The [KC637](http://www.teslakatalog.cz/KC637.html) seems to be reasonably similar to the [BC637](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/BC635-D.PDF), might be easier to find documentations for that.

It has a lower hFE but everything else should be ok. In general, if someone specified 2N2222 in a circuit, chances are high that just about anything will do.

[image]

**Be aware of the pinouts!**

The KC637 apparently looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> it requires 2N2222A transistor, is there any alternative?

Yes, the 2n3904 is directly equivalent in almost all cases.  Most suppliers will have large numbers of this and the 2222 in stock at all times due to their popularity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2N3904 (page mentions the 2222 also)